# Insert user defined node in the middle of xml file

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have the following xml file.

```
<Process xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>myDB</DatabaseID>
  </Object>
  <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
  <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
</Process>
```

Now i want to insert the MyCube sibling to the  tag or node.
I used linq to xml as below

```
 var mydoc = XDocument.Load("cubeProcess.xml");
XNamespace xmns2 = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine");
           mydoc
                .Element(xmns2 + "Process")
                .Element(xmns2 + "Object")
                .Add(new XElement(xmns2 + "CubeID"));
                mydoc.Save("C:\\Users\\ymihir\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\ConnectToExtrems\\ConnectToExtrems\\cubeProcess.xml");
```

But the output is changing as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Process xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>myDB</DatabaseID>
    <CubeID>myCube</CubeID>
  </Object>
  <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
  <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
</Process>
```

In this extra out put i dont want first tag `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
how to remove it with linq to xml and save the file. i am doing this dynamically.
Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This following line in your XML document is called *Xml Declaration*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

You can use `XmlWriter` to achieve you goal. Setting `OmitXmlDeclaration` property of `XmlWriterSettings` to `true` indicates that you do not need the *Xml Declaration* written to your xml file:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file4.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine";

doc.Element(ns + "Process").Element(ns + "Object").Add(new XElement(ns + "CubeID", "MyCube"));

var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true };
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("file5.xml", settings))
{
    doc.Save(writer);
}
```

Comment: @Meysam... thanks for response. But while saving the file it is giving exception that you dont have privileges to save the file5.xml file. how to resolve it?

Comment: @YSSS Where are you writing the file to? The account under which your application is running doesn't apparently have the necessary permission to write to that file location. Are you able to write to this address like before? `C:\\Users\\ymihir\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\ConnectToExtrems\\ConnectToExtrems\\cubeProcess.xml`